# Centralized way to empty the Cache object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, caching

I have to maintain an old asp.net application, and need to disable all access to the Cache object for debugging purposes. There are hundreds of pages that use the structure:

```
if (Cache["myobject"] != null)
{
   //get data from the cache
   //...
}
else
{
   //go to the DB, load the cache and send it to the client
}
```

I know I should refactor this code but, in the meantime, do you know of any simple and centralized way to empty (or disable) the Cache object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it will be of any help, but you can play with cache [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228248.aspx) and set, say, `privateBytesLimit` to `1` and `privateBytesPollTime` to `00:00:01`. My guess is that ASP.NET should basically remove all entries as soon as they're added. However, this might not be the case.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I don't think it's a good solution for production environments (my app now fires BeginRequest events all the time), but it's perfect testing.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it but this [helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478967.aspx) might give you what you're after.

Comment: Looks great. It's what I should do when I come around to re-engineering the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to clear the cache once, you can use this:

```
   foreach ( System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in HttpContext.Current.Cache )
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove( entry.Key as String );
```

Otherwise @Anton Gogolev solution looks good to prevent new entries.